# How can we load react native bundles globally

Tags: react-native, expo, bundles, packager

With **expo** projects, we can start bundles and change ** CONNECTION** to tunnel from the developer tools for loading bundles **globally**. How can we load bundles **globally** for **react-native** projects? I tried with the public IP address but bundles require to connect with the same network.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the implementation of [CodePush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/codepush/rn-get-started#plugin-installation-and-configuration-for-react-native-060-version-and-above-ios). You should be able to download the bundle from its remote location via native code and return its location via by overriding the `MainApplication.java`'s `getJSBundle()` method.

```java
// Override the getJSBundleFile method to let
// your runtime determine where to get the JS
// bundle location from on each app start
@Override
protected String getJSBundleFile() {
  // your implementation here
}
```

Same method using Objective-C for an iOS implementation by overriding `AppDelegate.m`'s `sourceURLForBridge` method:

```objectivec
- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
  // your implementation here
}
```

While for react-native the bundle must be available locally, your native code can download and swap the old bundle with the new one and than return the new bundle's location.

Comment: Have you tried it on your side?

Comment: I haven't got around to try it with a custom implementation, but this is how CodePush does it. If you don't mind me asking what exactly are you trying to accomplish?